# change variable in differrential equation with maple

Tags: differential-equations, maple

I have the following equation:

`eq1 := 2*diff(phi(r),r)/r+diff(phi(r),$(r,2)) + psi(r)^2*phi(r);`

I want to change the independent variable r to 1/z, that is the changing of variable r=1/z. How does I write this equation using the new variable

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the [dchange](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=PDEtools/dchange) command of the [PDEtools](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=PDEtools) package.

```
eq1 := 2*diff(phi(r),r)/r+diff(phi(r),$(r,2)) + psi(r)^2*phi(r);

                / d        \                                 
              2 |--- phi(r)|   /  2        \                 
                \ dr       /   | d         |         2       
       eq1 := -------------- + |---- phi(r)| + psi(r)  phi(r)
                    r          |   2       |                 
                               \ dr        /                 

PDEtools[dchange](r=1/z, eq1);

                        /                       /  2        \\                 
    3 / d        \    2 |     / d        \    2 | d         ||         2       
-2 z  |--- phi(z)| - z  |-2 z |--- phi(z)| - z  |---- phi(z)|| + psi(z)  phi(z)
      \ dz       /      |     \ dz       /      |   2       ||                 
                        \                       \ dz        //                 

simplify(%);
                  /  2        \                    
                  | d         |  4         2       
                  |---- phi(z)| z  + psi(z)  phi(z)
                  |   2       |                    
                  \ dz        /
```

Comment: Do you know how I change the derivative Diff(f,r)  to the derivative diff(f(r),r)

Comment: The `value` command changes the inert form `Diff(f(r),r)` into a call to the active `diff(f(r),r)`. For example, `value(Diff(f(r),r))`. Your comment is strange because you've used just `f` and `f(r)` and it's unclear whether you meant to use both as `f(r)`. Using both of those, distinctly like that, might make sense if you meant `D(f)(r)` instead, which can be converted using `convert(D(f)(r),diff)`. You should have asked this in a whole new Question, not as a comment here.

Comment: @acer....I have tried changing variables for DE:  $\frac{dy}{dx}=\,x^{2}y-\frac{2y}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}$ to $r$ and $r$as $\left\{r=\,x^2y, s=\,\log(x)\right\}$